# How to select one value from a two table join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm trying to achieve something in Laravel/MySQL and cannot seem to be pointed in the right direction for a solution. I can achieve what I am looking for with subqueries, but I have been told they are not as efficient as joins. And, I'm going to have to convert the solution for this into Eloquent/Query Builder, and the way I have it working with subqueries and unions doesn't seem to convert easily.

What I am trying to do is select one row from two possible tables, based on the `created_at` date of the row. I want to join this `created_at` value with my users table as a new column called `started_at`. Here is some sample data and how I can achieve the query with a subquery/union of the two possible tables that I can get the data from:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER, 
  first_name TEXT,
  last_name TEXT
 );

INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES 
(1, 'Craig', 'Smith'), 
(2, 'Bill', 'Nye'), 
(3, 'Bloop', 'Blop');

CREATE TABLE old_activity (
  id INTEGER,
  user_id INTEGER,
  firm_id INTEGER,
  amount INTEGER,
  created_at DATE
 );

INSERT INTO old_activity (id, user_id, firm_id, amount, created_at)
VALUES 
(1, 1, 3, 5.24, '2019-04-29'), 
(2, 2, 7, 4, '2019-03-28'), 
(3, 3, 4, 6.99, '2019-04-28');

CREATE TABLE new_activity (
  id INTEGER,
  user_id INTEGER,
  firm_id INTEGER,
  plays INTEGER,
  saves INTEGER,
  created_at DATE
);

INSERT INTO new_activity (id, user_id, firm_id, plays, saves, created_at)
VALUES 
(1, 1, 3, 10, 1, '2019-04-27'), 
(2, 2, 3, 12, 2, '2019-03-29'), 
(3, 3, 3, 6, 3, '2019-04-27');

CREATE TABLE firms (
  id INTEGER,
  name TEXT
);

INSERT INTO firms (id, name)
VALUES 
(1, 'apple'), 
(2, 'banana'), 
(3, 'orange');
```

```
select 
id,
first_name,
last_name,
(select created_at from old_activity 
 where user_id = users.id
 union
 select created_at from new_activity 
 where user_id = users.id
 order by created_at asc 
 limit 1) as started_at
from users
```

The query should only return the oldest `created_at` for a particular user in one of the two `activity` tables.

How can I achieve this with a join? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You could always use window functions:

```
select u.*, a.*
from users u left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by a.user_id order by a.created_at desc) as seqnum
      from ((select oa.* from old_activity oa) union all
            (select na.* from new_activity na)
           ) a
     ) a
     on a.user_id = a.id and a.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on SQL Fiddle, is it a working example? I have never used window functions.

Comment: @hoolakoola . . . Your tables don't work in db<>fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=da55402a1bf0f97c34bc189f68f7fabb.

Comment: Apologies, that is fixed now